# Get a new Date based on today's date minus or plus a specific number of days in one line

Tags: javascript, date

Simple question:

Get a date from 90 days ago:

This works:

```
const date90daysAgo = new Date();
date90daysAgo.setDate(date90daysAgo.getDate() - 90);
```

Can it be done in one line?

**Obs:** Vanilla JS only. No external libraries.

Comment: Like this: `const date90daysAgo = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 90);`?

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes. But if you do it like this it's no longer an instance of `Date`. I don't know why.

Comment: Oh, right - Because the `setDate` returns the number in milliseconds, I think the answer below solves that

Comment: What is the point of "in one line"? It will just create obfuscated code and multiple Date instances for what?

Comment: @RobG I agree with you in part. I just really like clean readability. You see that I create a variable named `date90daysAgo` that it's being initialized with today's value. I would like to initialize it with the `90 days ago value`.

Comment: You might do `let now = new Date(); let date90daysAgo = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - 90)` and you still have *now* to use for other things.

Comment: You are right. I though that it would have a simpler solution that I didn't know about, like: `new Date(-90*dayInMiliseconds);` or something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
console.log(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 90)));
```

Comment: @cbdeveloper try now

Comment: Thanks. It works. I upvoted your answer. But I'll wait to see if there are other options. I had done it like that before, but it's too unreadable. If this is the only way, I'll keep it in two line, too get better readability.

Comment: @cbdeveloper please also let me know if you get short hand of this.